# Optimizing django rest framework API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have created an API to get all the data from by database. There is a "deployment" table and a related table "sensors" which has a foreign key referencing the deployment, a one-many relationship. The serializer creates a nested JSON. Currently if I request all records it takes roughly 45 seconds to return the data (17,000 JSON lines).

How do I profile my Django application to determine what is the bottleneck?

Any suggestions on what can be improved to speed this up? Or is this is as good as it's going to get?

models.py

```
class deployment(models.Model):
    ADD_DATE = models.DateTimeField() #creation of record in db
    #...30 more fields....

class sensor(models.Model): 

    DEPLOYMENT = models.ForeignKey(deployment, related_name='sensors', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    ADD_DATE = models.DateTimeField() #creation of record in db
    SENSOR = models.ForeignKey(sensor_types, to_field="VALUE", max_length=50, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    #...5 more foreign key fields...
```

views.py

```
class GetCrtMetadata(generics.ListAPIView): #Read only
    serializer_class = CurrentDeploymentSerializer
    queryset=deployment.objects.all().prefetch_related("sensors")
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_fields = [field.name for field in deployment._meta.fields]
```

deployment app serializers.py

```
class CurrentDeploymentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #Returns deployment with sensors
    sensors = SensorSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = deployment

        fields = [field.name for field in deployment._meta.fields]
        fields.extend(['sensors'])
        read_only_fields = fields
```

sensor app serializers.py

```
class SensorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = sensor
        fields = [field.name for field in sensor._meta.fields]
```

Comment: You can try to prepare json manually (plain lists and dicts, without using drf serializers), this will be probably close to the best performance. You can also check actual sql to make sure you're not making extra queries. You can use cProfile to identify slow parts. And, yeah, serving large json will be slow in general, so it would be good if you can paginate it in some way

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into pagination and cProfile

Answer (score 1):

Why requesting all data at once?

Try to use Pagination to get that data you only need and request more if needed.

Comment: This API will be used to get data into matlab or a local pandas environment for further data analysis. I don't know the exact use cases yet, so I want to be able to send the entire data set. But it's likely the user will want to filter first (thus the filter backend code) and then only get back certain columns (still need to implement this, and would welcome suggestions). Other suggestions for transferring a large amount of data are also welcome.